# How do I initiate a tag synonym request?

Tags: discussion

Is it possible for non-mods to initiate tag synonym requests?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. **Click on any tag (e.g. [cylinder-head](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cylinder-head))**

   For the *cylinder-head* tag, the resultant URL looks like:

   ```
   https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cylinder-head
   ```
2. **Click on the synonyms link**

   Found in the blurb at the top of the page body.

   For *cylinder-head* tag, the resultant URL looks like:

   ```
   https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/tags/cylinder-head/synonyms
   ```
3. **Suggest a synonym**

   Found towards the bottom of the page, with a "Suggest" button next to it.

Comment: IIRC, you can only *suggest* a synonym if you have a certain amount of reputation in a given tag (could even be both tags).

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to - go to the page for the synonym you want to be the master (I think), click "synonyms" and there should be a "suggest a synonym" box at the bottom.

> Users with more than 1250 reputation and a total answer score of 5 or more on the tag, can suggest tag synonyms. Users with a total answer score (total upvotes minus total downvotes) of 5 or more on the tag, can vote for tag synonyms. Suggestions will be automatically approved when they reach a score of 4, and automatically deleted when they reach a score of -2.

Comment: I couldn't find an option to add another synonym on that page

Comment: hmm - which tag, and which synonym?

Comment: I wanted to initiate a request for *head* and *cylinder-head*.

Comment: ok - which way round?

Comment: I see a suggest button on both

Comment: Give me a few minutes to check on my desktop

Comment: https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/tags/cylinder-head/synonyms

Comment: Yes, I can see it. How did you get to that link though (from https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/tags/cylinder-head/info)

Comment: OK, I figured it out. You have to go through https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cylinder-head and click on the [synonyms](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/tags/cylinder-head/synonyms) link in the blurb at the top of the page